# Rook endgame book that goes through the strategy of such positions

Tags: endgame, strategy, rook-endgame

Consider this position:

```
[FEN "8/R4p2/P4kp1/7p/7P/4K1P1/r4P2/8 w - - 0 1"]

   1. Kd4 Rxf2 2. Rc7 Ra2 3. a7 Kf5 4. Kc4 Kg4 ( 4... Ra1 5. Kb5 Rb1+ 6. Kc6 Ra1 7.
Kb7 f6 8. a8=Q Rxa8 9. Kxa8 Kg4 10. Rg7 Kxg3 11. Rxg6+ Kh3 12. Rxf6 Kxh4 13.
Rg6 Kh3 14. Kb7 Kh2 15. Kc6 h4 16. Kd5 h3 17. Ke4 Kh1 18. Kf3 h2 19. Ra6 Kg1
20. Ra1# ) 5. Kb3 Ra6 6. Rc4+ Kxg3 7. Ra4 Rxa7 8. Rxa7 Kxh4 9. Kc3 g5 10. Rxf7 Kg3 11. Kd2 h4 12. Ke2 h3 13. Kf1 h2 14. Rh7 g4 15. Rh6
```

I want to read a book that explains the winning method of such positions. I read "100 Endgames you must Know" by De la Villa, and currently I'm reading "Endgame Strategy" by Shereshevsky. But none of them goes through examples like the one that I mentioned above. Let me know if you know any online references or books that talk about such positions. These positions are like one stage before the endgames that I saw in "100 Endgames you must Know".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dvorestsky's Endgame Manual has a section dedicated to this type of ending titled "Balance on One Wing and an Extra Pawn on Another". It is 31 pages in my third edition.

It contains exactly the position in your question.

It describes three plans for these kinds of positions when the extra pawn is on the 7th rank.

I recommend this book in general as a help for understanding the correct method in endgame play.

Answer (score 2):

First some disclaimers:

1. I will refer to mainly English language publications ( and Translations into English)
2. There will inevitably be other choices: I can only recommend the ones I know from my own experience or from collegial word of mouth.

3.You need to read and practice and play and loose a great many games to derive any benefit from these!

A.  There are several comprehensive General Endgame books that will have great coverage of rook endgames that well are worth looking at of which two stand out especially well :

1. Silman’s Complete Endgame Course -From Beginner to Master:  Jeremy Silman - Siles Press November 2006
   With detailed explanations and problems in the great teaching style of this Author
   Comprehensive coverage endgames in general
   You can dip into the table of contents online at what ever retail website you favour
   (Interestingly it is also available chess able with a free lesson to try)
2. Fundamental Chess Endings Karsten Muller & Frank Lamprecht:  Gambit Publications- Feb. 2023 Again Comprehensive coverage and eminently readable (I remember learning how to mate with N &B vs K from this)

B: Others:

1. Secrets of Rook Endgames John Nunn As the title suggests Rook specific Gambit Publications : thorough & up to date (also available on chessable)
2. Yuri Averbakh & Nikolai Kopayev Comprehensive Chess Endings Volume 5 Pergamon Press (1980’s was my edition- now out of print) But presently available via Ishi Press 2013
3. Dvoretzky’s Endgame Manual: Mark Dvoretzky (& revised by Karsten Muller) 5th Ed.  Russell Enterprises 2020 Advanced material.

4.Pal Benko Endgame Laboratory Ishi press 2007
(Collected Magazine Articles from the authors Chess life contributions in the 1980’s)

C. Software:

1.Total Chess Endings GM Alexander Panchenko: Extremely good value for money by comparison to other available sofware and you have the advantage and convenience of drill exercises to practice with.

2.Chessbase has a comprehensive set of Endgame   DVD’s from Lamprecht and Muller

D. Finally : Do not despair and enjoy the Quest whatever it brngs !